# Phone suddenly shut down and won't boot up

Tags: charging, hardware, xiaomi, power-on

My phone (Xiaomi Redmi Note 10, 2 years usage, the warranty just passed) suddenly shut down at 50% battery at normal usage when I clicked an app to open it and it will not boot up. I want to fix it myself due to privacy reasons, as I don't trust payed services and have experience in opening phones, but only to replace the screens.

I tried to turn it on on safe mode - unsuccesfully. I tried to charge it but it didn't even pop the animation of charging. Nontheless I left it for couple hours to charge and tried again - still not booting up. The USB connector is clean, dust-free and not loose. I tried different chargers. It is not detected by the computer when plugged in (checked in the Device Manager, Windows). I also called the phone from another phone to check if it's the screen's issue - I got "user out of service" message.

I tried to troubleshoot the connector and it was a surprise to me: I own a MakerHawk UM34C USB 3.0 tester and tried it on my working phone - readings were reasonable, approx. 13W of charging power. I tried it on bunch of other devices, with correct readings. I also tested a device with physical on/off switch and the device showed voltage of 5V when turned off (charger voltage) and voltage + amperage when turned on (with propper readings). **So when I plugged it in the phone and if the connector were bad then I should have the same reading as in the device with off switch. But what I got was device (tester) restarting constantly without even showing me the data, as if the connection was ok but the phone "intentionally" disconnected it repeatedly.** This means that the phone recognises the charger and disconnects it immediately. What does it imply? Is it the software issue?

I tried to open it like on the vid, using same tools but the glue seems to be too strong and it won't open so I can't check the battery itself without damaging the phone: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhC37fp4o7Y

**How should I troubleshoot the issue?**

These threads provided no help:

[Galaxy S4 Not booting up](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171472/galaxy-s4-not-booting-up)

[POCO M3 Pro 5g not booting up after unexpected shutdown. It does not charge as well](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247451/poco-m3-pro-5g-not-booting-up-after-unexpected-shutdown-it-does-not-charge-as-w)

In advance, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same issue with my Redmi note 10 pro. My phone abruptly used to turn off randomly anytime even when the phone has more than 50% of charge. Most of the time it used to get turned on after long pressing the power button but once it didn't turned on. I tried everything but didn't work.

How I solved the issue:
I open the phone disconnected all the cables and connected it back. After connecting it to charger, it turned ON!

You can try, if you have all the proper tools. I just needed a hair dryer, some cards and a screwdriver.

Hope this finds you helpful.